# Future tense and past perfect tense together?

Tags: grammar, future, past-perfect

Police **will** **have** the pictures **enlarged** in an attempt to identify the thief.

This sentence include two tenses. The former one is **will** for the future tense and the other is past perfect future tense. How can it happen and what's the grammar behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: You might also like to consider 'Q: Why _have_ these pictures _been_ enlarged ? A: They will have been enlarged for accuracy' where 'will have been enlarged', in the answer, is referring to a past event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “past perfect future tense.”

You are confusing the [*future perfect*](https://www.thoughtco.com/future-perfect-verbs-1690880) — ***you will have done** something* — with the future of *have* used as a [*causative verb*](https://www.thoughtco.com/english-grammar-causative-verbs-1211118) — ***you will have** something **done***. Note the word order: in a causative use, the participle or infinitive follows the object.

> He will have to have three teeth filled.
>   She’s having her house painted in bright colors.
>   The director had them wait in the outer office.

This is the future perfect:

> No matter how simple the first structure of your home may be, in a few years all settlers [*will have enlarged*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Jt5S-WC414AC&pg=PT45&dq=%22will+have+enlarged%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJl9PlmtjbAhVB7xQKHTHjB004ChDoAQhMMAc) and beautified their dwellings. — Lawrence Solomon, *Toronto Sprawls: A History*, 2007.

By a certain time (*in a few years*) a certain state resulting from an action will have occurred (enlargement and beautification of their dwellings).

This is the future of *have* as a causative:

> Competition finalists were awarded certificates and [*will have*](https://www.berwickshirenews.co.uk/news/chirnside-philosopher-has-local-competition-1-3758078) their photos *enlarged* and framed… *Berwickshire News*, 30 Mar. 2015.